# Is a 1D vector the same as a unit vector?

Tags: vectors, geometry

Is a 1D vector the same as a unit vector?
For example, is **A** = 3 **j** a 1D vector or a unit vector? It's magnitude is greater than 1 so it should be a 1D vector, and NOT a unit vector.

Comment: Two points: (i) Your example shows that a 1D vector need not be a unit vector since a unit vector has modulus 1, while 3 **j** has magnitude 3; (ii) This is really a maths question.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A unit vector is a vector with magnitude $1$. So $3\hat j$ is certainly not a unit vector, since it has magnitude $3$.

The most common definition of a one-dimensional vector is an element of a one-dimensional vector space (if we instead define a one-dimensional vector as a scalar multiple of a unit vector then *every* vector is a one-dimensional vector, and the definition is useless). If we follow the convention that unit vectors are labelled $\hat i, \hat j, \hat k$ etc. then $3 \hat j$ is presumably a member of a vector space with at least two dimensions, so it is not a one-dimensional vector either. On the other hand, $3 \hat i$ *could be* a one-dimensional vector, as long as the vector space to which it belongs only has one dimension.

So there are vectors that are both unit vectors and one-dimensional vectors ($\hat i$ and $-\hat i$ in a one-dimensional vector space); vectors that are one-dimensional vectors but not unit vectors; vectors that are unit vectors but not one-dimensional vectors; and vectors like $3 \hat j$ which are neither.

Comment: I always thought that $\vec i, \vec j, \vec k$ are 1D unit vectors along $x,y,z$ axis respectively. If for you  $3 \vec j$ is 2D vector, then $x \mathbf {\hat i} + y \mathbf {\hat j} + z \mathbf {\hat k}$ vector would not represent a point in 3D Euclidean space. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas I don't think I said that $3 \hat j$ is a 2D vector. If $3 \hat j$ is short for $0 \hat i + 3 \hat j$ then it is a 2D vector. If it is short for  $0 \hat i + 3 \hat j +0 \hat k$ then it is a 3D vector. Without more information you cannot tell the dimensionality of its vector space - I am just assuming that because the questioner wrote j rather than i, then the vector lives in a vector space with *at least* two dimensions.

Comment: You said _then $3 \hat j$ is presumably a member of a vector space with at least two dimensions_ Plain $N \hat j$ vector is scaled unit vector in $y$ axis, just that, no other points attached. Otherwise, interpretation possibilities are endless, because we may add as many zero vectors as we like to it. But, yes,- generally it depends what OP had in mind exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own question, the difference between a 1D vector and a unit vector is that unit vector has a magnitude of 1 where as a 1D vector is some scalar times the unit vector. Every unit vector is a 1D vector but not vice versa

Comment: Hmmm ... if you define a 1D vector as a scalar times a unit vector then isn't *every* vector a 1D vector ?

Comment: @gandalf61 no every vector is a superposition of 1D vectors, a 1D vector by itself is a scalar times the unit vector

Comment: Then you would say $3 \vec i$ and $3 \vec j$ are 1D vectors but $3 \vec i + 3 \vec j$ is not ? In that case you have made your definition of 1D vectors dependent on the co-ordinate system - if I rotate the co-ordinate axes by $45^0$ then $3 \vec i + 3 \vec j$ is now a 1D vector but $3\vec i$ and $3 \vec j$ are not.

Comment: @gandalf61 that is a good argument but then it's a matter of convention, I am assuming no transformations are happening because then you can have any sort of vector say if there could exist a vector which follows a semi circle then my definition would say that it's not a 1D vector but if you apply polar transformation or some transformation it would become 1D

Comment: Dimension applies to vector spaces, not vectors. The size of a basis determines the dimension of the space. The span of a single vector is one dimensional, even if that single vector is a continuous function, a matrix or any other element of a vector space.